Solving elliptic equations on the whole space?
I am interested in showing the existence of solutions to elliptic equations of the form
$$-\Delta u(x) + q(x) u(x) = f(x)$$
with $q \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (perhaps even $C^\alpha(\mathbb{R}^n)$) such that $q(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$
on the whole space of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Since this in on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ I can't use the "standard" elliptic theory of Evans or Gilbarg-Trudinger but I also can't use the Fourier transform because of the non-constant coefficients. Is there a systematic treatment of similar elliptic problems on the whole space that can give even distributional solutions?
Edit: One suggestion I was given is to consider a sequence of functions $u_\epsilon$ satisfying
$$-\Delta u_\epsilon(x) + q(x) u_\epsilon(x) + i \epsilon u_\epsilon (x)= f(x)$$
and try to extract a limit.
This problem certainly does have a solution for $\epsilon > 0$ by the self-adjointness of $-\Delta + q(x)$ but I don't know where to start in finding common sense conditions on $q(x)$ and $f(x)$ for a limit to exist. Somehow this also feels like overkill for such a simple looking problem.
Edit: The keyword for this problem seems to be "Limiting Absorption Principle" in the low energy limit.
